# Lazy load images in (svelte/sapper)

Tags: svelte

What would be best way to do this kind of lazy loading in Sapper:

1. Navigate to page containing image
2. First download small image from src
3. Start loading larger version from data-src and change that to src
   when ready
4. Navigate to another page
5. Come back to image page and have already loaded larger image there

If someone could help, I would be very happy :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [actions](https://svelte.technology/guide#actions). These are functions that run when an element is added to the DOM, and return an object with a `destroy` and (optional) `update` method.

You could do something like this ([interactive demo here](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.1.1&gist=e2c48acf753d19283bb98365b1d542c5)):

```js
<img
  alt="random photo"
  src="https://picsum.photos/100/50"
  use:lazy="{src: 'https://picsum.photos/400/200'}"
>

<style>
  img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
  }
</style>

<script>
  const loaded = new Map();

  export default {
    actions: {
      lazy(node, data) {
        if (loaded.has(data.src)) {
          node.setAttribute('src', data.src);
        } else {
          // simulate slow loading network
          setTimeout(() => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = data.src;
            img.onload = () => {
              loaded.set(data.src, img);
              node.setAttribute('src', data.src);
            };
          }, 2000);
        }

        return {
          destroy(){} // noop
        };
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Do we have a better way to do this in V3?

Comment: You can use the exact same technique https://svelte.dev/repl/26ba12b3fbd146eaaefc8b024a826da7?version=3.5.1

Comment: @RichHarris I know this is very old post, though based on the REPL, it's actually the same scenario I had, actually the approach I used is to use [await, then], however it requests twice, similar to what you have in the REPL, is there anyway to prevent it from requesting twice in a minimal way of coding?